# Vue3 Build - '@vue/compiler-sfc/package.json'

Tags: vue.js

Hope you can help
I'm trying to build my first Vue app and running `vue build src/App.vue` throws the following error

```
Building for production...(node:89260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module '@vue/compiler-sfc/package.json'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/loadCommand.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js:115:30
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:26)
    at PluginAPI.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/PluginAPI.js:145:25)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli-service-global/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/resolveAppConfig.js:9:22)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:89260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:89260) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "vue",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.9.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "vite": "^2.6.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

My node_modules/@vue/complier-sfc folder has a package.json file

Any help would be great

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use vue command because It's Vite, not Vue CLI project.

Comment: I've tried using vite. However, once the page loads there's no binding interaction. So a v-if works on first page load but doesn't change when the data changes. It works on localhost but not on build. I was hoping vue-cli would sort it

Comment: You not just tried to use it, you use it. The project was initialized with Vue, it's hardcoded to run with it. In order to switch to Vue CLI, you'd need to initialize a new project with it and move your source files there. The problem with bindings is XY problem. This shouldn't happen for properly written code, with Vite or not, consider fixing it instead

Comment: Similar problem. Here's what worked for me:  `npm i vue@3.2.29` (npmjs.com/package/vue/v/3.2.29) and then `npm run serve` and it fixed the issue. I'm a novice and can't explain why it worked, so I'm not submitting as an official answer. Good luck!